# black line through box

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

After adding link_to block, I now see a black line when I hover over the box -- see attached pic.  Tried changing many CSS properties but couldn't resolve the issue.  My view and CSS code are below.  Any ideas how to remove this black line?
[image: box with black line]

```
**View Code** 
<div class="categories">
   <ul>
      <%= link_to nqdc_user_path do %>
      <li>Sample Box</li>
      <% end %> 
   </ul>   
</div>

**CSS Code**

div.categories {
 margin-top: 25px;
 margin-left: 50px;
}

 ul {
     padding: 10px;
     color: white;
     list-style: none;
     text-align: center;
 }

 li {
   background-color: #4d4dff;
   padding: 25px;
   margin: 15px;
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 8px;
   font-size: 18px;
   color: white;
 }

 li:hover {
   background: #b3b3ff;
   color: black;
   text-decoration: none;
 }
```

Source Code

```
<div class= "categories">
 <ul>
  <a href="/users/1/nqdc">
   <li>Sample Box</li>
  </a>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce - https://jsfiddle.net/zjx7y2qb/2/

Comment: Please provide the generated code.

Comment: Also, links go **inside** `li` not the other way round.

Comment: @JonathanZúñiga source code is added above.  Thank you.

Comment: thanks @Paulie_D.  I suspect it's not showing the black bar, due to the fact that the code doesn't include the link_to block.

Comment: @richiepop2 thanks. As above said, the <a> tags go inside the list items.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanZúñiga.  When I put the link_to inside the li, I have to scroll over the text in order to click it.  I want the user to click on the box, not the text in the box.  This is why I used a link_to block over the li.  Make sense?  Thanks.

Comment: @richiepop2 but you can add padding to the link itself.

Comment: thanks @JonathanZúñiga.  I appreciate the help.  The <a> tags are added through the block.  I can't seem to resolve this problem -- bleh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link `a` element should go inside `li` element

```
 <li>
   <a href="">
         Sample Box         
   </a>

   </li>
```

[codepem](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVNzJP)

Comment: thanks @roll.  When I do this, the text needs to be clicked to go to the link.  I want the user to be able to click on the box, not the text.  This is why I created a link_to block.

Comment: I updated the css on codepen, check this, now all the box is clicked

Comment: thanks, @roll, but on my computer the user still has to scroll over the text to click the box.  Also, how do I add the link to the href code?  The link would be nqdc_user_path.  I think there might be something with bootstrap or something else interfering with this.  The 'a' code is added through the block, which I was told need to be outside the li, so that the user can click on the block instead of the text.

Comment: You can't write any html you want inside `a` tag the browser will render with errors, only can have as child `span`,`img`. Bootstrap don't brake anything, i think you should check line per line your code. If my code pen example works on you pc, then you check your css code, line per line.

Comment: Thanks for your notes here.  I discovered css code located in scaffolds folder, that was augmenting the code on my screen.  I removed it, and now it works perfectly.  Thank you again.